I have got 2 errors when trying to run an app on android studio and I can't resolv them
I was developing an android app with android studio 2.1 and at the end it gave me these problems while trying to run it:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --info option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

BUILD FAILED in 507ms
and this problem:
error: reached end of file while parsing
}
I tried searching on internet but nothing helped me

Could you please try to rerun again with ./gradlew assembleDebug --info and share the log, because.,
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

is a most common compilation build error, there can be many reason for this to occur
I think you should check the version and upgrade/downgrade it

Sorry how can I do it? I am new on the programming world

Change directory (cd) to the root directory of your Android project where the gradlew script is located and then do "./gradlew assembleDebug --info", also next time you post a question please add more info's like what language you are using etc.. it will be helpful
